# Error creating new azure resource group using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to new resource group in azure using terraform but i am getting following error

> Error checking for presence of existing resource group:
> resources.GroupsClient#Get: Failure responding to request:
> StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an
> error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client
> 'xxxxx' with object id 'xxxxx' does not have authorization to perform
> action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/read' over
> scope '/subscriptions/***/resourcegroups/stage-group' **or the scope
> is invalid**. If access was recently granted, please refresh your
> credentials.

This is code sample

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.7.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

#Create resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  name     = "stage-group"
  location = "eastus"
}
```

I am running this through github actions and passing ARM_CLIENT_ID,ARM_CLIENT_SECRET, ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID ,ARM_TENANT_ID . I dont have problem when running the same for existing resource.

Comment: What role did you assign to your Service Principal ? What is the scope ?

Comment: @Jul_DW These are the roles assigned to it ... Attribute assignment administrator ,Attribute assignment reader,Cloud application administrator,Reports reader

Comment: For existing resource i am able to apply changes , but not able to create new resource as its trying to read non-existent resource and throws error

Answer (score 2):

You have to [assign a proper role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current) to your Service Principal at a higher scope - `Subscription` or `Management group` level, with the rights to create `Resource Groups` (`Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/write`).

Most of the time, [Contributor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) is a good fit but you can look for more granular roles depending on your needs.

Comment: I have existing resource group that dev-group , here i am able to access and change other resources like keyvault,sql-db, function app with same service principle.

Comment: What role does your Service Principal has at subscription level ?

Comment: Contributor role